# How to retrieve a returned string by C function in Lua script?

Tags: c, lua

I have a Lua script which is calling a C function.
Currently this function is returning nothing.
I want to change this function to return a string, so at the end of this function in C I will push the string into Stack.
Inside the calling Lua script I need to get back the pushed string value.

**C initialization and registration with Lua**

```
void cliInitLua( void )
{
   void* ud = NULL;
   Task task;

   // Create a new Lua state
   L = lua_newstate(&luaAlloc, ud);

   /* load various Lua libraries */
   luaL_openlibs(L);

   /*Register the function to be called from LUA script to execute commands*/
   lua_register(L,"CliCmd",cli_handle_lua_commands);

   //lua_close(L);
   return;
}
```

**This is my c Function to return a string:**

```
static int cli_handle_lua_commands(lua_State *L){
   ...
   ...
   char* str = ....; /*Char pointer to some string*/
   lua_pushstring(L, str);
   retun 1;
}
```

**This is my Lua script**

```
cliCmd("Anything here doesn't matter");
# I want to retreive the string str pushed in the c function.
```

Comment: The code you have already would be a nice starting point for an answer to work off of.

Comment: See the 'In LUA' section of my answer.

Comment: It is Lua, not LUA. Lua is the Portuguese word for moon, not an acronym.

Comment: desculpe, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C you have something like

```
 static int foo (lua_State *L) {
   int n = lua_gettop(L);
   //n is the number of arguments, use if needed

  lua_pushstring(L, str); //str is the const char* that points to your string
  return 1; //we are returning one value, the string
}
```

In Lua

```
lua_string = foo()
```

This assumes you have already registered your function with lua_register

Pleas see the great [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4) for more examples on these sorts of tasks.

Comment: Unless you have very specific requirements accepting more arguments than you need is good practice (and matches general lua conventions).

Comment: @EtanReisner That is a great point. I took the liberty of editing my answer per your suggestion. I still left the check in, because if you get more arguments you will have to clear them from the stack.

Comment: You don't need to clear them. lua handles the stack for you at the lua<->C transition points. You can simply push your string and return 1 and everything works. If you were calling this function from another C function you would need to maintain stack cleanliness though.